# async.js methods inside async.js methods

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

*Disclaimer: new to JS and everything around it. :)*

I was wondering if we could nest async functions within one another

I have a waterfall method in node:

```
/**
 * POST new travel wish
 */
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;

    console.log(req.body);
    // add properties: customer_id and timestamp
    var date = new Date();
    //...

    var notif;

    async.waterfall(
      [
         // find the User
         function(next){
           db.collection(userCollection).findOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.session.userID)}, next);
         },

         // insert a new travelwish
         function(user, next){
           notif = {
             'username': user.username,
           };
           // TODO: add a async.parallel
           db.collection('travelwishlist').insert(req.body, next);
         },

         // setup timer for processing and send confirmation
         function(insertedTravelWish, next){
           NotificationManager.sendConfirmationNotification(notif);
           next(null, insertedTravelWish);         
         }
     ],

       // waterfall callback --> send http response.
       function (err, insertedTravelWish) {                  
         res.send(
           //if everything is ok the system sends the travel wish ID to the client otherwise error
           (err === null) ? { msg: insertedTravelWish[0]["_id"] } : { msg: 'err' }
         );
        }
     );
});
```

I want to insert multiple items instead of just one.

**I think i can do this with parallel, but can I put it inside the existing waterfall?**

Comment: i donT know.. i thought it d be messy and ppl would suggest a cleaner alternative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you totally can do it, here is some piece of example

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        callback(null, 1);
    },
    function (arg, callback) {
        callback(null, arg1 + 1);
    },
    function (arg, callback) {
        async.parallel([
            function (_callback) { ... },
            function (_callback) { ... },
        ], finalCallback);
    }
]);
```

just a little tip, make sure you proivde different names for the callbacks (so you won't call the other one) if I've 2 nested functions that requires a callback most of the time I name them as `callback` `_callback` `__callback`

Comment: cool! But, about the callbacks, why donT u make the changes in your answer? callback --> _callback

Comment: @Zortkun, I was sure its clear enough, there is many examples on async's github page. anyway the `_callback` should be the arg in the inside parallel functions.